# Is Python treating ^ as a white space in split()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, split

I have a list of error codes and one of these codes is:

```
Dial code generated note %d on stn ^char, cct %d^cct_chk^cct_chk
```

Any terms that contain a `%`, `^` or `$` symbol is a variable and I need to replace those entire variable terms with `<*>`.

So the above line should look like:

```
Dial code generated note <*> on stn <*> cct <*>
```

To do this I have written:

```
message = "Dial code generated note %d on stn ^char, cct %d^cct_chk^cct_chk"
for term in message.split():
    if '^' in term:
        message = message.replace(term, '<*>')
    if '$' in term:
        message = message.replace(term, '<*>')
    if '%' in term:
        message = message.replace(term, '<*>')
print (message)
```

For most messages this seems to have worked. But for this example I am getting:

```
>>Dial code generated note <*> on stn <*> <*> <*>^<*>_chk^<*>_chk
```

It appears as though it is treating the `^` just like a whitespace, otherwise the entire last term should have been replaced with `<*>`.
Could someone tell me why this is?

Comment: You've already replaced all of the `%d`s with `<*>`, so by the time you get to that last term it's no longer what you have in the split version. Short answer: no, it isn't. But your output doesn't quite match the code you've posted.

Comment: Ah ok. Do you know how I would fix it in that case so it gives me the output I am after?

Comment: Using your example code I get `Dial code generated note <*> on stn <*> cct <*>^cct_chk^cct_chk` output which is different from your example output.

Comment: Yes it probably is. I have been through a few different combinations and have probably copied in the wrong one. The important part is the desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` has a third parameter to allow to limit the number of replacements. In your case, your problem is caused by a replacement string being used more than once: `%d` is replaced in last word.

A simple fix is to limit the number of replacements to 1:

```
message = "Dial code generated note %d on stn ^char, cct %d^cct_chk^cct_chk"
for term in message.split():
    if '^' in term:
        message = message.replace(term, '<*>', 1)
    if '$' in term:
        message = message.replace(term, '<*>', 1)
    if '%' in term:
        message = message.replace(term, '<*>', 1)
print (message)
```

BTW, just printing `term` and `message` on each iteration would have made the error evident...

Answer (score 2):

You can split and assemble back again the pieces you like:

```
message = "Dial code generated note %d on stn ^char, cct %d^cct_chk^cct_chk"

message = ' '.join('<*>' if any(item in term for item in '^$%')
                    else term for term in message.split())
print(message)
```

Output:

```
Dial code generated note <*> on stn <*> cct <*>
```